# Integral $\int \frac{9-e^{x}}{e^{8x}}dx$

Tags: integration

$$
\int \frac{9-e^{x}}{e^{8x}}dx
$$

What is the trick to getting these done without a lot of work? I have lots of simpler examples. Do I just do usub twice and try to stay organized? What is my strategy?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\left(9\int e^{-8x}\mathrm{d}x\right)-\left(\int e^{-7x}\mathrm{d}x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Try dividing the integral into two integrals using the distributive law (take the 9 outside of the first one btw), then simplify the second one (resulting in  the integral of e^-7x), and then  use u substitution for each one of them. Both are straightforward integrals, you'll be done in no time.